# How to remove the query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Note: i little speak english

I have a problem with `mod_rewrite`.

I want to replace my site name, I want this URL

```
 http://www.oldsite.com/index.php?v=contact
```

rewritten to URL

```
http://www.newsite.com/page/contact with 301 rewrite.
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=contact
RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.newsite.net/page/contact [R=301,L]
```

But I'm getting the query `http://www.newsite.net/page/contact?v=contact`. 
I dont want `?v=contact`, I want `http://www.newsite.net/page/contact`.

Comment: Brushed it up a little, I hope you don't mind :) (but I'm not a native english speaker either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> Note: Query String
>   The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string, containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string, to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. **When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.** To combine a new query string with an old one, use the `[QSA]` flag.

So you should probably have:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.newsite.net/page/contact? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://dranger.com/weblog/entry/apache_mod_rewrite_strip_query_string.html), you should be able to write:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.newsite.net/page/contact$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you know what `$1` means? It is a back-reference to the first capture group of the pattern. But as there is no capture group this does not make much sense.